# How to print homedirectory of a user #c

Tags: c

I wrote a program that prints the homedirectory of a user but it's not working.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
char cmd[256], name[256], homedir[256];
int main()
{
    printf("Username: ");
    fgets(name,256,stdin);
    sprintf(cmd, "grep %s /etc/passwd|awk -F : '{print $6}'", name);
    FILE *fp = popen (cmd, "r");
    if (fp)
    {
        fgets(homedir, sizeof homedir, fp);
        printf("%s %s", name, homedir);
        pclose(fp);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

it prints:

```
Username:
```

and after I type 'Paul' it prints nothing and I don't know why.

Comment: You have a mistype, you wrote  `nume`

Comment: Why do you ignore compiler errors?

Comment: sry for that, i edited it.

Comment: Would not such a critical error prevent the generation of an executable image?

Comment: 'sry for that, i edited it.' - copy/paste. please.

Comment: I dont get any error when i compile this programm

Comment: what do you mean by copy/paste?

Comment: It means you have to provide a [mcve] **with your actual problem**, not some code you don't actually use.

Comment: I just want to know why it is not working. I tried to figure out but i couldn't find a reason.

Comment: Do you not get it?  The code you originally posted was NOT the code you tested.   Your original code could not possibly compile because ot the name typo that would not have happened if you had copy/pasted in your code text instead of.. whatever you did :(

Comment: Anyway, step through your code line-by-line with your debugger and tell us which line fails/misbehaves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `fgets(name,256,stdin);` line gets the `\n` character as an input after you're pressing enter. Then your `cmd` string looks like this:

```
grep <your username input> 
   /etc/passwd|awk -F
```

Change the line `fgets(name,256,stdin);` to `scanf("%s",name);`.

Comment: It works ... until you type in a string a thousand character long and then your program crashes and burns (usually with a `Segment fault` error).

Comment: I didn't say the program is perfect , I only addressed the problem that was mentioned and its cause.

Comment: You could improve your answer by changing `scanf("%s",name);` to `scanf("%255s,name);`

Answer (score 0):

The fgets function also returns the newline character, so effectively you're executing the command `grep username`.

But to get the home directory, don't manually parse /etc/passwd. Use getpwnam for this.

Comment: Ok i will try .